# Can I get a notice when I have a comment liked or flagged?

Tags: feature-request, comments, flagging, up-votes

Often people vote or like a comment, but unless I check every comment I post I will not get a notice. Is there any way to get notice when my comments gets liked? What about when a comment is flagged? Much time could be saved if the OP has a chance to correct a problem before it goes to the moderator??

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to get notified about likes or flags on comments. If you think about it, the only reason that you get notified when questions get voted on is when your reputation changes. Vote or flags on comments don't cause reputation changes, so there is not notification.

I did a quick search on meta.stackexchange.com and I didn't see any relevant questions.

Comment: I have a question ban there to:(